# Deadlock issue on my server

Tags: domain-access

I am getting the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: INSERT INTO {domain_source} (nid, domain_id) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1); Array([:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 101712 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 0)

This happens `hook_node_update()`. Do you have an idea on how to solve the issue?

Comment: Try finding a _reason_ for the deadlock with `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`.

Comment: Deadlocks hardly ever appear without explicit locking (or at least long and complicated transactions), so it's either a really old rdbms version (could you tell version? ) or careless module code. Is this question still valid? There were some issues in module's queue in that area.

Answer (score 0):

After applying this [Patch](https://drupal.org/files/domain-empty_query-issue.patch), these errors are reduced however not fully rectified. This patch prevents empty delete queries being run and thus reducing the load on the domain_source table.