# Deadlock found in domain source Node Insert .- Drupal7

Tags: domain-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deadlock issue on my server](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38682/deadlock-issue-on-my-server)

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: INSERT INTO {domain_source} (nid, domain_id) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1); Array
>   (
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 362400
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 2
>   )
>    in domain_source_node_insert()

Can you explain me why this error happens?

Comment: Could you tell us when you obtain this error?
Which version of drupal? Which database?

Comment: I have a module that saves nodes programatically on cron run. Version : D7 database : mysql